# Touchpad doesn't work when laptop is sideways

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, microsoft-surface-pro-3

I'm using a Surface Pro 3 with a type cover, newly upgraded to Windows 10. Whenever I turn the laptop on its side, my touchpad stops working. Upside-down works fine, however. I toggled each combination of tablet mode and rotation lock, and the issue still occurs. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft acknowledges that this behavior is intentional and that perhaps they should consider allowing it to be disabled (feature request "passed along").  There's nothing you can do to fix this, currently.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfpro-surfgetstart/clip-on-keyboard-stops-working-when-surface-pro-is/2681835b-d904-4ad2-8aff-ee1e657ac68d